# Why do questions with answers appear with the Unanswered ones?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

While looking for questions to answer, I use the "Unanswered" selection but find questions with answers among them.

There are other categories and sorts that don't seem to be working well which is a mild frustration. Is this the norm or a glitch which needs attention?

Comment: I have clicked through various combinations and see obvious (to me) contradictions due to imprecise definitions such as unanswered questions with answers notwithstanding their relevance to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the header.

> **unanswered questions**
>
> [image]

All of the questions on the page meet that criteria.

Comment: The newest unanswed questions do have answers which appears contradictory. I believe that the "unanswered" s/b "unaccepted" to be correct and in line with other designations. It's confusing and a point of contention. It should be on a list of points needing some clarification.

Comment: Until an answer gets some indication that it is at very least useful to *someone* (upvote, accept), it's not really accurate to call the question "answered" - at best, we could say "responded to". I could post waffle recipes in response to every question here, and at best I'd have answered only 60-70% of questions on the site. @Stan

Comment: @Shog9 At the risk of starting a discussion, please see my attempt at clarifying my question with a comment.

Comment: Rather than getting into a discussion, I'm gonna refer you to this blog post, @Stan: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/